# float contains more than 4byte

Tags: c

I want to write the value 4.0 in my txt file from reading of binary file, which looks like

> 0000000: 046a 6f68 6e03 646f 6500 0000 0140 8000  .john.doe....@..
>
> 0000010: 00

I want this output.

> 0000000: 6a6f 686e 2064 6f65 2031 2034 2e30 0a    john doe 1 4.0.

my problem is writing the float values.

```
char buffer[NAME_MAX];
float *gpaPtr;
float gpaNumber = 0;

fread(buffer, sizeof(float)  , 1, fp);
gpaPtr = buffer;
gpaNumber = (float)*gpaPtr;
printf("%f\n", gpaNumber);
clearArray(buffer);

fprintf(fp2,"%s %s %d %f\n" ,firstName, lastName, idNumber,gpaNumber );
```

when I use this code to write in the file, it's out is this.

> 0000000: 6a6f 686e 2064 6f65 2031 2034 2e30 3030  john doe 1 4.000000
>
> 0000010: 3030 300a

my code write more than I want.

I used float pointer to point first address of buffer and it supposed to write only size of float I think(both gpaPtr and gpaNumber are float)

I guess the problem is occurring by 32 single precision type and 64 double precision.

please let me know how to get only the right size of gpa and why this is occurring.

Comment: [This `printf` (and family) reference might help](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). As would quite a few tutorials on using `printf` all over the Internet.

Comment: Um... Where did you get the idea that the length of *textual* decimal representation of `float` value is somehow related to `sizeof(float)`? Your `printf` creates a decimal representation of `float` value, which might easily be 10, 20 or 100 characters long. `sizeof(float)` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I solved with using fprint. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please read some documentation about `printf()` function. Pay close attention to the "precision" field for the `%f` conversion specifier.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf